# "The mean recognition rate of the first 6 attitudes is above 50%”，correctly？

Tags: grammaticality

The mean recognition rate of the first 6 attitudes is above 50%.

It is there anything wrong？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, no - the sentence is fairly easy to understand. You should have used 'correct?' in the title, rather than 'correctly?', but that is the only problem I can see.

As to whether there's anything wrong with the fact that the mean recognition rate of the first 6 attitudes is above 50%, that's something you'd have to tell us. :P

Comment: All right. What I mean is there anything wrong of is/are confusion or incorrectly using of "s"？

Comment: No, because you are talking about the mean recognition rate (singular) rather than the 6 attitudes (plural). E.g. "The 6 attitudes are varied, but the mean recognition rate is above 50%."

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to express that the recognition rates of all the 6 attitudes are above 50%, should I say: (1) All the recognition rate of the first 6 attitudes are above 50%. (2) The recognition rates of all the 6 attitudes are above 50%. Which one is better and "native-like" (should I say authentic or native-like, lol)?

Comment: @Ping - Had you incorporated these comments into your original question, it might not have been closed so quickly. There's no need to skimp on the details of a question. In fact, I'd encourage the opposite; sometimes these small details improve a question, because they make it easier to pinpoint the cause of confusion.